# calling a method in IBAction method

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to create a program that when i tap the screen, alert will popup..
So I change the UIView to UIControl, and create an IBAction method When tap the screen, Then i found a method on the internet the print the tap location.

this is my code:

```
-(IBAction) Touch:(id)sender{
    [self touchesBegan];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];
    CGPoint currentPos = [myTouch locationInView: self];
    NSLog(@"Point in myView: (%f,%f)", currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
}
```

and its give's me an error...
What to do?!?!

Comment: which error does it give you ?

Comment: `What to do?!?!` Telling us what the error actually is would be the best starting point I can imagine.

Comment: i know what your error is, remove [self touchesBegan] you are 1. calling this method without the necessary parameters, so you are probably getting unrecognized selector sent to instance, and second the uiview calls this method on its own, you just need to override it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `[self touchesBegan]` from your "Touch" method
you are

```
1. calling this method without the necessary parameters, so you are
probably getting unrecognized selector sent to instance, 
2. the uiview calls this method on its own, you just need to override it
```